# boto3 find object by metadata or tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to **search** objects in S3 bucket by object's metadata or tag key/value? (without object name or etag)

I know about `head_object()` method ([ref](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object)), but it requires a `Key` in its parameters.

It seems that `get_object()` method is also not a solution - it takes the same argument set as `head_object()`, and nothing about metadata.

As I can see, neither `get_*` nor `list_*` methods provide any suitable filters. But I believe  that such an opportunity should be in S3 API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The `ListObjects()` API call **does not accept search criteria**.

You will need to retrieve a listing of all objects, then call `head_object()` to obtain metadata.

Alternatively, you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a regular CSV file containing a list of all objects and their metadata. Your program could use this as a source of information rather than calling `ListObjects()`.

If you require something that can do real-time searching of metadata, the common practice is to store such information in a **database** (eg DynamoDB, RDS, Elasticsearch) and then reference the database to identify the desired Amazon S3 objects.